# Simple Membership Accounts not Writing to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to set up Simple Membership on a 4.0 MVC4 website. I am using a SQLexpress instance on my local machine for development.

My Default Connection string worked to write the tables when I hit an [Authorize] action the first time. And the login action appears to hit the database and return an incorrect username or password error. Since there is nothing in the db, all entries will be incorrect.

I believe that the problem is the provider. The ASP.NET configuration tool, which I use to write the first credential, tells me that the default provider is AspNetSqlProvider. I've tried to set up a Membership section in the web config file, clear that default and make sqlmembershipprovider the default. That results in an assortment of errors, with the configuration tool telling me it can't connect to the provider and the debugger stalling on the InitializeSimpleMembershipAttributes ensure initialized filter, which prevents a second creation of the tables.

I would be very grateful for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.Net configuration tool is for use with the full ASP.Net membership service, not the Simple Membership tables.  If you are wanting to add users to Simple Membership, you simply add the user in the tables directly using SQL Management Studio.  If you modify the providers for the much more complex ASP.Net Membership service, you will render Simple Membership useless.

From [ASP.Net blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

> WSAT is built to work with ASP.NET Membership, and is not compatible with Simple Membership. There are two main options there:
>
> 1. Use the WebSecurity and OAuthWebSecurity API to manage the users and roles.
> 2. Create a web admin using the above APIs.
>
> Since SimpleMembership runs on top of your database, you can update your users as you would any other data - via EF or even in direct database edits (in development, of course)

Comment: I'd be grateful for some details on adding the users to sql management studio. Didn't work for me, I suspect because I didn't know how to construct the password salt. I also cannot access the register view without being in

Comment: was correct in his answer, which solved the problem. I realized after I wrote the previous comment that I had removed the anonymous access to registration. Now that I understand the simple membership provider, I appreciate how much easier it is than asp.net membership. Many thanks, Andrew.